# Balanced braces/brackets/parens regex in Ruby

Tags: ruby, regex

I came across a regex in the pickaxe Ruby book for finding balanced brace-expressions, and I'm trying to build upon it to get a regex that matches balanced braces/brackets/parens.

The original:

```
re = /
  \A
    (?<brace_expression>
      {
        (
          [^{}]                 # anything other than braces
        |                       # ...or...
          \g<brace_expression>  # a nested brace expression
        )*
      }
    )
  \Z
/x
```

My version so far:

```
re = /
  \A
    (?<brace_expression>
      (?:
        (?<brace> { ) | (?<bracket> \[ ) | ( \( )
      )
        (
          [^{}\[\]()]           # anything other than braces
        |                       # ...or...
          \g<brace_expression>  # a nested brace expression
        )*
      (?(<brace>) } | (?(<bracket>) \] | \) ) )
    )
  \Z
/x
```

It correctly matches "{xyz}", "[xyz]", "(xyz)", and correctly fails to match something like "{xyz]", but the recursion isn't behaving as I'd expect. It fails to match nested brace expressions like "{[]}". What am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

Interesting question. Your current pattern looks quite good. What about using alternation instead of conditionals which seem to be unreliable when using together with recursion.

```
re = /
  \A(                            # start group 1
    \(([^)(\]\[}{]+|\g<1>)*+\)|  # parens & set group 2
    \[\g<2>*+\]|                 # brackets
    \{\g<2>*+\}                  # braces
  )\z                            # group 1 end
/x
```

- `\g<1>` is the [subexpression call](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Regexp.html#class-Regexp-label-Subexpression+Calls) to first group which holds the pattern between start and end.
- `\g<2>` is a call to group 2 which holds `[^)(\]\[}{]+|\g<1>` for [reducing the pattern](https://regex101.com/r/oV5mE4/2).
- `*+` is a [possessive](http://www.regular-expressions.info/possessive.html) [quantifier](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Regexp.html#class-Regexp-label-Repetition) to improve failing-performance if unbalanced.

[See demo at Regex101 (PCRE)](https://regex101.com/r/gM1oY0/2) or [Rubular <sup>v1.9.3+</sup>](http://rubular.com/r/uXQE8Lulwj)